# echo php variable that contain php echo code

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that echoes a variable:

```
<?=echo $myVariable;?>
```

`$myVariable` is data that I pull from a MySQL variable and it may include code like `php echo` itself in it:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    Hello $data['assigned_vars']['first_name'];<br />
    your email <?=$data['assigned_vars']['email'];?><br />
    your password <?=$data['assigned_vars']['user_password'];?>    
</div>
```

I'm using `ob buffering` to store the entire string and then `return`. How can I execute the PHP code inside the PHP string?

Comment: Why are you storing a string that contains PHP code in a database?

Comment: Using `eval`. However, **this is a very bad idea.**

Comment: Why are you also using php short tags with echo ? Isn't it an either/or situation...

Comment: those are just html templates that echo data. i think that using mysql database is a good way to manage this html codes.

Comment: I was also going to suggest `eval`, but the data stored is not really a valid PHP statement. The real solution is to use a template system.

Comment: instead of $storing the template in a variable, why don't you include it?

Comment: i only have 5 pages, so building a template system is an headache

Comment: note: We are not being mean when we say that everything about this is a horrible idea, we are trying to help you avoid some very painful learning experiences in your near future.

Comment: i'm building a very light real time application and want to avoid any overhead code to run, that's why i try to avoid using template system that includes overhead. 

anyway, eval is not an option since it will try to parse the html code

Comment: `<?=` is the equivalent of `<?php echo`. adding echo inside it is useless, since echo has no return value that `<?=` would output anyways.

Comment: php short tags are useful and helps the code to have cleaner look. Fred, i do appriciate deceze but yet i'm looking for a solution

Comment: @sd1sd1: To understand just how bad of an idea it is, you're practically giving everyone on the internet the keys to your house, plus the forklift to extract your TV, sofas, and everything you have, and then give them the wrecking ball to annihilate the place. Think about it this way, and then tell me if you're still absolutely 100% sure you want to go down that road. (**Hint: You don't**)

Comment: Madara, i really don't understand why. all i'm using is a small mysql table with 2 fields on a server that only parse small php code. this server does not apache, mysql sever or anything else. it only runs php

Comment: and another word on this issue - php is a templating system, so why to build another templating system on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` function,but it makes big security problem for you.

```
echo eval($string);
```

but security exception can occurred here,for example following code.

```
$string = "base64_decode(bXlzcV9xdWVyeSgnREVMRVRFICogRlJPTSBVU0VSJyk7)";
//mysql_query('DELETE * FROM USER'); 
echo eval($string);
```

and it empty your `USER` table.

Comment: eval is not an option because security but mainly because i run html code and eval shall fail on it

Comment: @sd1 You either evaluate the code or you don't. Which do you want? And `eval` does not fail on HTML if done properly. Read the manual.

Answer (score -1):

i think that i found my solution. i can just file_put_contents to create temporary html file, then simply include it and then delete the file

Comment: you can use jade,smarty or other template engine.

Comment: Moein, why use template system on a template system? php IS A TEMPLATE SYSTEM

Comment: That is exactly the same as using `eval`, only more complicated. And if you're writing to a file anyway, why not keep the code in a file to begin with instead of the database? Sorry, but you have everything bass ackwards!

Comment: deceze, the database allows to connect it to cms